# How to add an array item to Custom iOS Target Properties in Xcode 13 where Info.plist has been removed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist, xcode13

As of Xcode 13, Info.plist has been replaced by `Custom iOS Target Properties` ✅ you can access this via Project → Target → Info.

My goal is to add a property `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` which contains an array of items. I can tap on the + button and add this row, but I can't for the love of me add an item to the array!

How do I add an item to an array type?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Make sure the item is set to an `Array` type (which it is in your screenshot).
- Right click (or `ctrl` click) on the row you have selected and choose "Add Row"

[image]